# Why does initial hash value in GetHashCode() implementation generated for anonymous class depend on property names?

Tags: c#, roslyn

When generating `GetHashCode()` implementation for anonymous class, Roslyn computes the initial hash value based on the property names. For example, the class generated for

```
var x = new { Int = 42, Text = "42" };
```

is going to have the following `GetHashCode()` method:

```
public override in GetHashCode()
{
   int hash = 339055328;
   hash = hash * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode( Int );
   hash = hash * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode( Text );
   return hash;
}
```

But if we change the property names, the initial value changes:

```
var x = new { Int2 = 42, Text2 = "42" };

public override in GetHashCode()
{
   int hash = 605502342;
   hash = hash * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode( Int2 );
   hash = hash * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode( Text2 );
   return hash;
}
```

What's the reason behind this behaviour? Is there some problem with just picking a big [prime?] number and using it for all the anonymous classes?

Comment: It seems more useful to me if you use different constants so that objects of different types are "more" different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there some problem with just picking a big [prime?] number and using it for all the anonymous classes?

There is nothing wrong with doing this, it just tends to produce a less efficient value.

The goal of a `GetHashCode` implementation is to return different results for values which are not equal.  This decreases the chance of collisions when the values are used in hash based collections (such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`).

An anonymous value can never be equal to another anonymous value if they represent different types.  The type of an anonymous value is defined by the shape of the properties:

- Name of properties
- Type of properties
- Count of properties

Two anonymous values which differ on any of these characteristics represent different types and hence can never be equal values.

Given this is true it makes sense for the compiler to generate `GetHashCode` implementations which tend to return different values for different types.  This is why [the compiler](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compiler/AnonymousTypeMethodBodySynthesizer.cs,188) includes the property names when computing the initial hash.

Comment: I see. I guess the hash codes with the constant initial value could blow up in your face if you put instances of different types into `HashSet<object>` for whatever reason.

Comment: However, if differentiating hashes for the objects of different types is generally a good idea, why are the amonymous classes the only case when it's done by default? I haven't found a single example of this in BCL yet. For example, Int64, TimeSpan and DateTime basically share the implementation and `0L.GetHashCode()` == `TimeSpan.Zero.GetHashCode()` == `default( DateTime ).GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @HellBrick the differentiation is only interesting when it's likely the values will be inserted into the same hashing structure.  It's actually not uncommon for anonymous values of different types to do this.  But it's probably pretty rare, if ever, that a hashing structure will have both `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` values as keys.

Comment: Huh, I'd never expect putting anonymous values of different types into one dictionary / hashset to be popular enough =) But it explains a lot. Now I get the picture, thanks.

Comment: @HellBrick customers always do something you weren't expecting them to do ;)

Answer (score 4):

Unless someone from the Roslyn team steps up we can only speculate. I would have done it the same way. Using a different seed for each anonymous type seems like a useful way to have more randomness in the hash codes. For example it causes `new { a = 1 }.GetHashCode() != new { b = 1 }.GetHashCode()` to be true.

I also wonder whether there are any bad seeds that cause the hash code computation to fall apart. I don't think so. Even a `0` seed would work.

The Roslyn source code can be found in [`AnonymousTypeGetHashCodeMethodSymbol`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compiler/AnonymousTypeMethodBodySynthesizer.cs,ed31274c994e907d). The initial hash code value is based on a hash of the names of the anonymous type.